# Azure SQL Performance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database S1 Standard (20DTU) and I'm seeing vast variations in performance.  I have a number of queries that power a set of reports on a small web site.  When running these queries through the Management Studio the performance varies from 0 to 60 seconds.  The site isn't public so there's no traffic yet - only me.  Looking at the DTU usage, it spikes at around 50%.  Can anyone help me understand where the performance difference is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1104.troubleshoot-and-optimize-queries-with-azure-sql-database.aspx to troubleshoot your query performance. Enabling Query data store is another option if you are on V12.

There could be various factors that imapcts query performance, buffer pool, sql instance restarts because of azure maintenance (which clears buffer pool) etc.